# Android: Constructor is ambiguous when I pass Null, but not when I pass a variable assigned to Null

Tags: java, android, arraylist, adapter, android-arrayadapter

I wrote the following statement to create an `ArrayAdapter<String>`,

```
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.fragment_result_titles, R.layout.row_listview, arrayList);
```

But I got the error that the constructor call is ambiguous.

I understand that when null is passed, it is not clear which among `ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, T[] objects)` and `ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId, List<T> objects)` are we calling.

But then I tried this:

```
ArrayList arrayList = null;
ArrayAdapter<String> arrayListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.fragment_result_titles, R.layout.row_listview, arrayList);
```

**This does not give the error, although I am still passing `null`, isn't it?**

Why is this happening?

Comment: because the compiler resolved the ambiguity, when you passed the arrayList reference

Comment: ... also you will get NPE if you pass null there(just right after you set this adapter to the AdapterView(ListView) because underlaying code will try to call `((List)null).size()`) ... you should use this constructor: `ArrayAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This happens because in the second case, arrayList is a variable of type ArrayList which happens to be null. In the first case, there is no type information about the parameter so the compiler doesn't know which method should be invoked. You can make the first case work by using `(List) null` as the argument.

Answer (score 2):

When you set null like this:

```
ArrayAdapter(context, resource, textViewResourceId, null);
```

You are setting a null pointer (pointer to nothing place) and this null can be any object.

By other hand, when you do this:

```
ArrayList arrayList = null; 
ArrayAdapter arrayListAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(getActivity(), R.layout.fragment_result_titles, R.layout.row_listview, arrayList);
```

You are creating an **ArrayList type pointer** in memory (pointing to no object, but **with type**). Java only can assign a object to a variable of the same type (or inherited type). So, this are not ambiguous yet and compiler can know which method must be use.

Comment: But isn't the memory only allocated when we create the object using the `new` operator?

Comment: Yes when you do this: ArrayList array; you are doing a pointer to nothing, but with type. When you do this: array = new ArrayList(), you are allocating memory and **poiting array variable to new allocated object**. But the type exists since you create the pointer.

Answer (score 2):

To add to Petter's answer, the following will also work:

```
new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), R.layout.fragment_result_titles, R.layout.row_listview, (ArrayList)null);
```

precisely because you are supplying the type information that Java needs in order to solve the ambiguity of which constructor to use.